gasLimit unpredictable error - using nodejs22, visual studio 1.93, solcjs 0.8.19. Remix works fine , but using the reactjs app, i got the error
Follow the error below:
index.ts:269 Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (error={" reason":" execution reverted: You must pay at least 0.001 ETH per donut","code":"UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT","method":"estimateGas","transaction":{"from":"0x27aB18527735f51333F26cA7cfF20843310A372c","gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x3b9aca00"},"to":"0xA225d1D70cDeBf00470c319a977F898a35be04Fd","data":"0xefef3`
Hello ALL,
I get the  gas Limit error " can't estimate the gas" using a React app created. I can read the contract without problems, but just when I try execute the function " purchase" that pass the { account, value} , I get the problem. So, I'm using nodejs22, React, visual studio 1.93 and Solcj0.8.19. The contract created works fine using remix IDE, all functions. I tried to deploy in different blockchains (local node and other chain), downgrade the nodejs22, visual studio version, solcjs19 to different versions, still getting the same error.
Also, if I use { gasLimit:600000} the functions is submitted to the blockchain without gas error, but doesn't work.
